# AngularJS how can select value from ng-options

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

i am inserting value in select ng-options and i want to select in dropdown for particular month.
this is return all 12 month arrray, so how can i fetch only selected month from dropdown.

**Script:**

```
$scope.Month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
 $scope.selectmonth = $scope.Month;

 $scope.SaveReport = function () {

    PrintReportRepository.save(
            {
             SelectMonth: $scope.selectmonth,
             },
```

**html**

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectmonth" ng-options ="months as months for months in Month">{{months}}</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting first item selected use `$scope.selectmonth = $scope.Month[0]`, by setting `$scope.selectmonth = $scope.Month` U setting whole array as a model

Answer (score 0):

use this code: see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5xFdlBlx41Iq2S1WxoUU)

controller:

```
$scope.Month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
 $scope.SaveReport = function () {
    console.log('SelectMonth', $scope.selectmonth);
 }
```

html:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectmonth" ng-options ="months as months for months in Month" ng-change="SaveReport()"></select>
```